# Change Style without editing .tex

Tags: document-classes, output

I have a latex PDF being generated from another language. It is designed to produce html output, but also produces the latex PDF output.

I do not have access to the latex, so I can't modify it, but I can add .sty or .cls files to be used in the conversion process that will affect the PDF output.

What is the best tool for modifying latex styling when you don't have access to the tex itself? Classes? Styles? Included .tex files?

Comment: I'd simply include a TeX file that does the necessary adjustments.

Comment: Does anyone have any good examples of tex files used in this way?
i.e. just by including the additional file (so, no inline references) the formatting is modified in the primary tex file

Comment: That's a bit vague if you don't have access to the tex files. Do you have access to the log? If so, you could check which document class is used.